# FFmpeg on Linux Video Size in Preset

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, resize, encoding

Hi everyone I am trying to create a preset to encode my videos with ffmpeg through this file:

```
#video options
s=716x402
vcodec=libx264
minrate=900k
maxrate=1100k
bufsize=1500k
vprofile=high
level=4
field_order=progressive

#audio options
acodec=libfdk_aac
b:a=44.1k

#metada options
movflags=faststart
```

but it doesn't accept the first line "s=716x402" and returns this error:

> Invalid option or argument: 's=716x402', parsed as 's' = '716x402'

If I remove that line everything goes smoothly but fact is that I need to change the size of the output.
I know that in the command line this

```
>ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -s 716x402 output.flv
```

works so I'm guessing there is another way of telling the video size in a preset file.
Does anyone know how?

Please take notice that I'm calling this preset through the -fpre flag inside the ffmpeg comand line

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try "size=...." ???

Comment: I've reproduced your error using the same library and preset. It also comes up when using a different library libavpx

Comment: no, haven't tried "size=". I will as soon as I will be able to, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need the correct option for the x264 library. I think its

`resize:[width,height]`

Take a look at the [x264 options page](http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/X264_Settings#output)

Seems like it works via command line because it is not using the preset options of x264. When using the preset, `s=resolution` is not recognized.

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -s 716x402 output.flv`

is different from

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -vpre "YOUR PRE FILE" output.flv`

where `-s` in the first line is an option of the ffmpeg while in the second line,  `-s` is trying to be used as a x264 option.

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I will be able to, thank you!

Comment: it would be great for me to use `resize:width=716,height=402,fittobox=both`. But how do I write it in a preset file?